# crashing found nil while unwrapping optional value

Tags: swift, xcode, null, unwrap

Hi all I'm creating a chat app, using firebase.

when I get to the screen to create a channel it crashes saying found nil while unwrapping optional value. If i go back into the app the channel has been created so i presume it is finding nil when changing viewcontrolers and there must be nothing in the database for the new channel under messages. below is the code and where it crashes.

```
var channelRef: FIRDatabaseReference?

private lazy var messageRef: FIRDatabaseReference = self.channelRef!.child("messages")
```

then it crashes here...

```
private func observeMessages() {
    messageRef = channelRef!.child("messages")
```

this function is called on view did load

Comment: `channelRef` is `nil`. When you unwrap it (`!`), it crashes. Please read [What does fatal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu/32170457#32170457)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of force unwraps you should use and `if let` like this:

```
if let channelRef = channelRef {
     messageRef = channelRef.child("messages")
} //maybe add an else and do some logic if value is not there
```

Or you could declare `var channelRef: FIRDatabaseReference!` if you expect it to always be there and be of this type

Comment: Cheers for your comment I tried the solution but then it moves the same error above to the first part of the code.     var channelRef: FIRDatabaseReference?
    
    private lazy var messageRef: FIRDatabaseReference = self.channelRef!.child("messages")          when i hover over self it shows chanel ref as nil

Comment: it is `nil` because doing `private lazy var messageRef: FIRDatabaseReference = self.channelRef!.child("messages")` doesn't work since `self.channelRef ` is `nil` at that point...you need to initialize that first and then initialize the `messageRef ` you should do just `var messageRef: FIRDatabaseReference!`